# Reading a string from a .plist file error

Tags: objective-c

```
data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"INFO" ofType:@"plist"]];
    name = [[data objectForKey:@"Name"]stringValue];
```

I am getting a SIGABRT error on when I try to give create `name`. All the names are alright. What could be wrong?

I have a `INFO.plist` file in my project. It has a row of type String. The value is `Test`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided `name` is an `NSString *`, the following ought to work:

```
NSString *name = [data objectForKey:@"Name"];
```

`NSDictionary`'s [`-objectForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey:) returns the object, which will already be an `NSString`. (I'm not sure why you're calling `-stringValue` on it, but that could cause a crash or exception).